# How to set font size when class extends from Activity not BaseAdapater

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-adapter

Hi there my android activity has a listview whose font size i need to increase/magnify. I have read solutions where you override getview of baseadapter for this. But my class extends Activity not BaseAdapter. How can i do in this case? Here is my code

```
public class SaltnPepperActivity extends Activity implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

private ListView menuList;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saltn_pepper);

    menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id){
       ....
 }
    });

}
```

This Activity is called via intent from main activity

**MainActivity**

```
ImageButton saltnPepperButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSaltnPepper);

    saltnPepperButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //goto new page
            Intent menuIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SaltnPepperActivity.class);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Starting new Activity");
            ///startActivityForResult(menuIntent, 0);
            startActivity(menuIntent);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Started new Activity");
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
Code for binding list to data

```
Log.d("Menu", "Binding category to menulist");
        //load categories
        try{
            //get names from categories
            //ArrayAdapter<Category> catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Category>(this,  R.layout.menulist, R.id.nameText, categories);
            CategoryAdapter catAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, R.layout.menulist, categories);
            ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
            list.setAdapter(catAdapter);
            //SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: where is your adapter set inside of listview?

Comment: @Samra are you able to see list? Where is your menuList.setAdapter(adapter) method ?

Comment: ok i will share that too..i am binding with data by parsing xml file

Comment: code is added in the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Gurvinder and Jaydeep. I found my setAdapter function in another class CategoryAdapter where i had defined Custom Adapter class inheriting from ArrayAdapter. Setting fontsize there, it works!